# When exactly do you get the coin from the map in Civilization?

Tags: civilization-board-game

The rules are clear about how long can you keep a coin that's on the map

> **Coins on the map**
>
> Coins gained from squares on the map – whether from a natural  gold deposit in the mountains or from a building placed in a  square – are only kept as long as the player retains control of the square (i.e., the square is contained in the outskirts of one of the player’s cities or one of the player’s scouts remains in the square to gather from it).

But when do you get them, in which phase? Does it happen in the Trade Phase, like with other resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't played this in many years but checking rules link [here](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/support/civilization-rules.pdf) it seems my memory is right.  You dont 'gain' coins in the same way you get trade or production.  Your coin dial is just showing how many coins you have in total.  If you read the bit after what you quoted it should be clearer.

> Coins gained from squares on the map – whether from a natural
>   gold deposit in the mountains or from a building placed in a
>   square – are only kept as long as the player retains control of the
>   square (i.e., the square is contained in the outskirts of one of the
>   player’s cities or one of the player’s scouts remains in the square
>   to gather from it). If an enemy figure blockades the square
>   containing the coin, it is lost while the enemy figure remains
>   there (see page 27). Similarly, if a building granting a coin to a
>   player is destroyed, the coin is lost.

So if I move a scout on on to a space giving me a coin I move my dial up straight away.  if I lose that space then I lower my coin dial.   Its not a resource thats gained every turn and goes up each time.  if it was a player with 3 coins on tech and city outskirts would win in just a a few turns.